# Term for "still deciding on/looking for a religion"

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone said that it was "agnostic," but as an agnostic I know that's not it. But I was wondering if there was a word for someone who hasn't yet found a religion. Thanks!

Comment: **Seeker** was the word often used, in evangelical Churches and societies I've been part of, for someone trying to come to terms with eternal truths (pre-dates the Harry Potter usage!)

Comment: _someone who hasn't yet found a religion but believes in God_, a child :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, that person is a *seeker*.

Google dictionary defines *seeker* as "someone making a search or inquiry; "they are seekers after truth"

It does not apply to a one particular religious or spiritual system of belief, that is, you do not need to be seeking Buddha or Allah or God or the Goddess, you can be seeking all or some other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Seeker** is correct, but for point of reference, here's some other terms:

- **Theist**: one who believes in God(s)
- **Atheist**: one who disbelieves in God(s)
- **Gnostic**: one who knows their stance is correct
- **Agnostic**: one who does not know their stance is correct for sure

These terms can be combined.

Where most people would describe *atheists* (or *militant atheists*) as ones who know there there no god and denounces god as such, they are actually referring to *gnostic atheists*.

One can be an *agnostic atheist* which is where you do not believe there is a god but cannot or currently do not know for sure.